# SQL table result command in textbox instead of the result in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Here is the table setup I have:

```
int | Design_1
0   | Design_A
1   | Design_B
2   | Design_C
```

Here is my code for the form:

```
var design = (from d in BikePartsDataContext1.handlebars
              where d.@int == "0"
              select d.Design_1);
this.textBox1.Text = design.ToString();
```

What I am trying to do is make the `textBox1` text have the value of the `Design_1` value from the row where `@int` is 0.

All works fine until I get this as the text value for `textBox1`:

```
SELECT [t0].[Design 1] FROM [dbo].[handlebars] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[int] = @p0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the first record then based on Id?

```
// at top of file so you can use the extension methods
using System.Linq;

// code
var design = (from d in BikePartsDataContext1.handlebars
              where d.@int == 0 // i removed the quotes add them back if this is truely a string/sql varchar
              select d.Design_1).Single(); // use single to ensure only 1 record will get selected
this.textBox1.Text = design; // design will now be the value of Design_1
```

Some notes:

- Single will throw an exception if no records are found OR if more than one record is found.
- If there can be 0 records use `SingleOrDefault`
- If there can be more than 1 record and you do not care which one is used then use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`
- I assumed your id was an int and not a string so I removed the quotes around `0`, add them back if this is not the case

You can also rewrite it using only lambda expressions:

```
this.textBox1.Text = BikePartsDataContext1.handlebars
    .Where(x => x.@int == 0)
    .Select(x => x.Design_1)
    .Single();
```

Comment: The question you asked at the beginning of your post was correct.
Thank you for the help! I did not think of using `.Single()`!
Unfortunately, the `@int` value was recognized by the program as a `string`, so the quotations were necessary.

Comment: I did not consider lamba expressions either, as I still have to learn about them, so thank you very much for the help!